# Is display property (e.g. flex or block) needed when element length and width have been set beforehand?

Tags: css, display

Since setting the length and width size have permanently set the element size, adding `display:flex` or `display:block` is not needed, isn't it?

Comment: display & size are two orthogonal features. Elaborate more what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you mean actually.
The display property is usually affecting the children elements.
When you use display, it modifies the behavior of the children elements and sometimes their width (e.g. `display: flex` will make the width of the children 100%). But it's overwritten if you set a specific width.

More infos on the display property here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display